# Posting to Webhooks via Zapier Code

Tags: javascript, json, webhooks, zapier

I am having trouble getting a Webhook to post from Zapier's Javascript code step.  I need to use a Code Step because I want to send variable information to the same Webhook.  I believe I have found a way to send the data I want to the Webhook.

```
fetch('https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/974762/krbqch/', { method: 
   'POST', body: 'a=1, another: textfield'})
        .then(function(res) {
            return res.json();
        }).then(function(json) {
            console.log(json);
        }).then(function() {
        callback();
      })
      .catch(callback);
```

I am getting an error that states "Error: 
You must return a single object or array of objects."  This seems like this is something simple that I am not doing.  I am just not sure what it is.  Hoping I can get some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

Your big issue is that you're calling the `callback` function without any params. You want to either pass nothing (`callback(null, {})`) or call it with some data (`callback(null, {response: json})`).

Either way, it's important that the first parameter be `null` if the function should exit successfully. Past that, I'd look at your `body`. Right now you're setting values two different ways (`=` and `:`), which feels like it won't do what you expect.

All that said, you can still use variable data in Webhook steps (easier to configure than code) by mapping in values from previous steps. That might be an easier way to go about it.

​Let me know if you've got any other questions!

Comment: Great, worked well.  Only thing is that the Webhook will not receive the data unless I set the other zap to Catch a Raw Hook and it does not separate headers.

Comment: Could either of you share a complete working example code? Thanks! :)